# fixed position does't work in both of firefox and chrome, opera, but only safai, css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

At the beginning, fixed position doesn't work in all browsers, then i search here, and put `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` into my css code, then safari works but others still don't work, why? 
What else can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: share your code here or create fiddle to view your problem

Comment: Which property is not working, Fixed or Transform... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); // For safari, chrome and opera
-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); // For Mozilla
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); //IE and similar`
```